# i am trying to get json object value but did not get see object is image

Tags: arrays, json

[json image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXBUU.jpg)

i am trying to get json object value but did not get

```
json = JSON.parse(json);

alert(json.observations[0].dateCorrect);
```

Comment: Please add some more details. This question is not solvable the way it is.

Comment: Wow, your description almost makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json is probably wrongly encoded. The actual key is `"observations[0].dateCorrect"`. See matching quotes:

[image]

So you'll have to do `json['observations[0].dateCorrect']` to get what you want, but you better (if you can) change how json is encoded first.

To make it clearer:

```
var data = JSON.parse(json);
var key = 'observations[0].dateCorrect';
alert(data[key]);
```

Answer (score 0):

that's coz the thats not JSON, this is a string you need to parse it before accessing it.
try this

```
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
alert(obj.observations[0].dateCorrect);
```